# OneDrive files which appear in Finder but not in terminal?

Tags: terminal, mac, finder

It sounds crazy, I know. Usually its the other way round - you can see files in terminal which are not visible in Finder.

I have a problem which is the other way round. I have a folder - `/Users/me/OneDrive/stuff/sa` that has one PNG in it. OneDrive is saying there is a problem with the file and the folder. I can see both in the Finder, and if I do "info" there is nothing wrong with them (e.g. no spaces or dodgy characters).

However, If I open Terminal, and do `cd /Users/me/OneDrive/stuff` then `ls -ld sa` it shows nothing, and if I do `ls` it is missing form the list. `pwd` shows I am in `/Users/me/OneDrive/stuff`.

I am a Unix sys admin - I have tripple checked and what I am seeing should not be possible.

The file and folder are quite old, and have not changed recently.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say you open Terminal and do `cd /Users/OneDrive/stuff`, did you mean to say you do `cd /Users/me/OneDrive/stuff` ?

Comment: The OneDrive Finder extension may not be syncing properly (going by the error you mentioned).  In other words, it's telling Finder it's there when in reality, it's not.  Try restarting the OneDrive extension

Comment: @Allan this could be it.  How does one restart the onedrive extension on mac?  I have tried restarting the onedrive process, which doesnt seem to help. The dir is in finder even if I kill onedrive.

Comment: Right click the OneDrive icon in the menu bar, click the three vertical dots and then select "Quit One Drive."  Restart it by relaunching.  Easiest way is to press `Command-Space` and type "OneDrive"